# Multi Boot Raspberri Pi and amd64 OS

Tags: dual-boot, raspberry-pi, raspbian, live-usb, persistence

How I can Multi boot Pi OS 64 bit with persistence for Raspberry pi (arm64) and ventoy with OS with no persistence on another partition, while the Pi OS is the default?

Comment: how do you boot an amd64 OS on an ARM machine?

Comment: I wanted to use the same usb for pi os and for ventoy for my main computer as live usb.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's **probably not possible**. Ventoy and bootloaders specifically produce machine dependent code. It means that the program compiled for the x86_64 platform won't work at aarch64. That's why there is Ventoy for aarch64 - https://www.ventoy.net/en/doc_aarch64.html. When you download Ventoy for the Linux you have binaries for architectures:

- aarch64
- i386
- mips64el
- x86_64

Maybe there might be some dirty hack (for example, using MBR partitioning for x86_64 and UEFI (with offset [ I have no idea if it's possible]) for aarch64?), but I have never heard about it.

Comment: I want the ventoy to run it from 64 bit computer, and the Pi OS to use the same usb on raspberry pi arm64, while it have persistence, and I couldn't find a tool for that.